# Converting image to Greyscale

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, rgb, grayscale

I know that we can convert RGB image to greyscale by using `PIL` or `PILLOW`. We can do this by importing `Image`. One way that can be used to do this is as follows.

`from PIL import Image
img=Image.open('Sample.jpg').convert('LA')
img.save('greyscale.png')`

Can we convert RGB image to greyscale without using a python package? I wan to learn that way. Any help, how can I do this?

Comment: That depends a lot on the encoding

Comment: @bendl , but how can I do this? Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: If you can get the individual pixel data, you can sum the RGB values

Comment: @bendl sorry I don't get your point.

Comment: To convert to greyscale, all you need is the brightness of each pixel. The brightness is just the sum of the brightness of the individual colors.

Comment: @bendl More likely the *average* of the R, G and B values than the sum.

Comment: @MarkSetchell True, I was leaving out the last step where you scale it back to the correct size, which turns out to be the same as averaging. Just calling it an average is more clear thouhg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look a data from a RGB image with Pillow you will get a turple with 3 values, or 4 if you read in RGBA mode. In grayscale (L) you have only 1 value. With Python you have so many libs to convert a RGB to L, and they have different ways/methods. To convert RGB to L you need make the sum of RGB and have manys formulas like

```
 (max(R, G, B) + min(R, G, B)) / 2 #lightness method
 (R + G + B) / 3 # average method
 0.21 R + 0.72 G + 0.07 B # luminosity method
```

but to create a image without a lib I don't know, because I create a method to draw a image using Pillow